# JSP page won't work :Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: jsp, jstl

**Here is all the code from my register.jsp file**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="utf-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<html>
<head>
    <title>register</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="register.jsp" method="post">
        account:
        <input type="text" name="user"></input><br>
        password   :
        <input type="password" name="password"></input><br>
        <input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit"></input>
        <input type="reset" name = "reset" value = "Reset"></input>
    </form>
</body>
    </html>

<c:set var="user" value = ${param.user } scope = request></c:set>
<c:set var="password" value = ${param.password } scope = request></c:set>
<sql:setDataSource driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" user="scott"     password="669193"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/orcl"/>
<sql:query var="query" sql = "select * from users where user =? and password = ?">
   <sql:param value = ${user }></sql:param>
   <sql:param value = ${password }></sql:param>
</sql:query>
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${!empty query.rows}">
    <jsp:forward page="Hello.jsp"></jsp:forward>
</c:when>
</c:choose>
```

when  I open it, the browser display this error **HTTP Status 500**

Any help is really appreciated:) thanks!

**Here is stack trace**

> type Exception report
>
> message
>
> description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling >this request.
>
> exception
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class >for JSP
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>
> root cause
>
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
>
> root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.register_jsp
>     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>     java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>     java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
>     org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:598)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:329)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
>     org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)

Comment: Have you added the oracle classes to your class path? And part of your page seems invalid, you should quote all attributes for the tags.

Comment: @RogerLindsjö I have added the oracle classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you post the entire stack trace? Also, why are you embedding DB connection logic in the view (JSP)? They should be in the controller somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. It's my first attempt to use the JSTL and EL. And I want to use it do all things.

Comment: Remove all the JSTL code from your JSP and just start with the plain HTML (so remove everything below the </html> tag). Try to get your page to render. If it renders properly, add in one thing at a time and see if you can isolate which line is causing the issue.